# Using data-attribute and click function to push data value to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each, custom-data-attribute

I am using data-attributes to hold values for product names. When a user clicks on `.compProdBlock` I want the `data-fastName` to populate within the `fastTitle` field.

In my attempt I am using the `push` and `each` function. I am not getting any errors, but the data is not populating.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Only the top two choices have data associated with them.

```js
var fastShowName = [];
$('.compProdBlock').click(function() {
  $('.compProdBlock').each(function() {
    fastShowName.push($($(this).data('fastName')));
  });
  $('#fastTitle').html(fastShowName);
});
```

```css
#compSec2Block1,
#compSec2Block2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 80vh;
}

#compSec2Block1 {
  width: 40%;
}

#compSec2Block2 {
  width: 60%;
}

#compSec2Block2inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.compProdBlock {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.compProdBlock img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.pTitleWrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.boxTitleWrap {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  width: 100%;
}

.boxTitle25 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="compSec2" class="sec">
  <div id="compSec2Block1">
    <h3 class="dG" id="fastTitle"></h3>
  </div>
  <div id="compSec2Block2">
    <div id="compSec2Block2inner">
      <div class="compProdBlock" data-fastName="Standard Fastener" data-fastImg="">
        <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
        <div class="pTitleWrap">
          <div class="boxTitleWrap">
            <h2 class="boxTitle25">Standard Fastener</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="compProdBlock" data-fastName="Universal Fastener">
        <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
      </div>
      <div class="compProdBlock">
        <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
      </div>
      <div class="compProdBlock">
        <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the `data-* attribute` should be `data-fast-name` instead of `data-fastName`.

No need for loop you could set the data of the current clicked element using :

```
$('#fastTitle').text( $(this).data('fast-name') );
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.compProdBlock').click(function() {
    $('#fastTitle').text($(this).data('fast-name'));
  });

  $('.compProdBlock:first').click();
});
```

```css
#compSec2Block1,
#compSec2Block2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 80vh;
}

#compSec2Block1 {
  width: 40%;
}

#compSec2Block2 {
  width: 60%;
}

#compSec2Block2inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.compProdBlock {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.compProdBlock img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.pTitleWrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.boxTitleWrap {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  width: 100%;
}

.boxTitle25 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="compSec2" class="sec">
  <div id="compSec2Block1">
    <h3 class="dG" id="fastTitle"></h3>
  </div>
  <div id="compSec2Block2">
    <div id="compSec2Block2inner">
      <div class="compProdBlock" data-fast-name="Standard Fastener" data-fastImg="">
        <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
        <div class="pTitleWrap">
          <div class="boxTitleWrap">
            <h2 class="boxTitle25">Standard Fastener</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="compProdBlock" data-fast-name="Universal Fastener">
        <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
      </div>
      <div class="compProdBlock">
        <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
      </div>
      <div class="compProdBlock">
        <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a way to get the first `.compProdBlock` data to show on page load?

Comment: I will also be inserting an as a data-attribute. Would this still work with the method you are using or would I have to use the push function then? I would have mentioned this in my question, but I figured the push function would be the answer either way.

Comment: You're welcome, sure you could call `$('.compProdBlock:first').click()` at the start of ready function

Comment: Updated my answer for _show on page load_, not sure what you mean by _I will also be inserting an as a data-attribute_.. :(

Comment: I will be including an image in a `data-attribute`. Right where I have `data-fastImg=""` Then in the first block (where the title is going), I will also be showing an image associated with the product clicked on.

Comment: so you have just to change `data-fastImg` to `data-fast-img` and use the same approach as we do for the `fast-name`.

Comment: Gotcha. I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Glad I could help brother, HAPPY CODING.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `$('#id').attr('data-fastName')` instead of `$('#id').data('fastName')`
2. If you only want to display the clicked item as title, you don't need to push all the fastName into an array.

```js
var fastShowName = [];
 $('.compProdBlock').click(function () {
  $('#fastTitle').html($(this).attr('data-fastName'));
 });
```

```css
#compSec2Block1, #compSec2Block2 {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 80vh;
}
#compSec2Block1 {
 width: 40%;
}
#compSec2Block2 {
 width: 60%;
}
#compSec2Block2inner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.compProdBlock {
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 border-right: 2px solid #000;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.compProdBlock img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
.pTitleWrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.boxTitleWrap {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 width: 100%;
}
.boxTitle25 {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="compSec2" class="sec">
   <div id="compSec2Block1">
    <h3 class="dG" id="fastTitle"></h3>
   </div><div id="compSec2Block2">
    <div id="compSec2Block2inner">
     <div class="compProdBlock" data-fastName="Standard Fastener" data-fastImg="">
      <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
      <div class="pTitleWrap">
       <div class="boxTitleWrap">
        <h2 class="boxTitle25">Standard Fastener</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div><div class="compProdBlock" data-fastName="Universal Fastener">
      <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
     </div><div class="compProdBlock">
      <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
     </div><div class="compProdBlock">
      <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 issues in your code. First you created array and that array would not be printed inside `<h3>` tag. because it's still an object. you can't print that. and another is after creation on DOM. Data part will be insensitive from case. so if you taking `$(this).data('fastName')` then it will return undefined. you will need to use `$(this).data('fastname')`

```js
var fastShowName = '';
 $('.compProdBlock').click(function () {
  fastShowName = '';
  $('.compProdBlock').each(function () {
   fastShowName = fastShowName + $(this).data('fastname');
  });
    
    console.log(fastShowName);
  $('#fastTitle').html(fastShowName);
 });
```

```css
#compSec2Block1, #compSec2Block2 {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 80vh;
}
#compSec2Block1 {
 width: 40%;
}
#compSec2Block2 {
 width: 60%;
}
#compSec2Block2inner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.compProdBlock {
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 border-right: 2px solid #000;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.compProdBlock img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
.pTitleWrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.boxTitleWrap {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 width: 100%;
}
.boxTitle25 {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="compSec2" class="sec">
   <div id="compSec2Block1">
    <h3 class="dG" id="fastTitle"></h3>
   </div><div id="compSec2Block2">
    <div id="compSec2Block2inner">
     <div class="compProdBlock" data-fastName="Standard Fastener" data-fastImg="">
      <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
      <div class="pTitleWrap">
       <div class="boxTitleWrap">
        <h2 class="boxTitle25">Standard Fastener</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div><div class="compProdBlock" data-fastName="Universal Fastener">
      <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
     </div><div class="compProdBlock">
      <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
     </div><div class="compProdBlock" data-fastName="Standard  32b Fastener">
      <img src="https://s.shld.net/is/image/Sears/s_102316_Tools_Holiday_VisualNav_2-qm-$cq_width_250$" alt="Standard Fastener">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify the javascript to get the attribute 'data-fastName' of the div:

```
var fastShowName = [];
    $('.compProdBlock').click(function () {
        $('.compProdBlock').each(function () {
            fastShowName.push($(this).attr('data-fastName'));
        });
        $('#fastTitle').html(fastShowName);
    });
```

Comment: Answers should be more that just "Change your code to this". They should clearly explain what the problem was and how the solution addresses it.